# Mutliple constructors in python calling the same routine

Tags: python, oop, constructor

I am writing a class with multiple constructors using `@classmethod`. Now I would like both the `__init__` constructor as well as the classmethod constructor call some routine of the class to set initial values before doing other stuff.

From `__init__` this is usually done with self:

```
def __init__(self, name="", revision=None):
    self._init_attributes()

def _init_attributes(self):
    self.test = "hello"
```

From a classmethod constructor, I would call another classmethod instead, because the instance (i.e. `self`) is not created until I leave the classmethod with `return cls(...)`. Now, I can call my `_init_attributes()` method as

```
@classmethod
def from_file(cls, filename=None)
    cls._init_attributes()
    # do other stuff like reading from file
    return cls()
```

and this actually works (in the sense that I don't get an error and I can actually see the test attribute after executing `c = Class.from_file()`. However, if I understand things correctly, then this will set the attributes on the class level, not on the instance level. Hence, if I initialize an attribute with a mutable object (e.g. a list), then all instances of this class would use the same list, rather than their own instance list. Is this correct? If so, is there a way to initialize "instance" attributes in classmethods, or do I have to write the code in such a way that all the attribute initialisation is done in **init**?

Hmmm. Actually, while writing this: I may even have greater trouble than I thought because **init** will be called upon return from the classmethod, won't it? So what would be a proper way to deal with this situation?

Note: Article [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427379/python-how-to-call-an-instance-method-from-a-class-method-of-the-same-class)] discusses a somewhat similar problem.

Comment: Instead, couldn't you just make `_init_attributes()` a `@staticmethod` and explicitly pass it the object whose attributes need initializing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'r understanding things correctly: `cls._init_attributes()` will set class attributes, not instance attributes.

Meanwhile, it's up to your alternate constructor to construct and return an instance. In between constructing it and returning it, that's when you can call `_init_attributes()`. In other words:

```
@classmethod
def from_file(cls, filename=None)
    obj = cls()
    obj._init_attributes()
    # do other stuff like reading from file
    return obj
```

However, you're right that the only obvious way to construct and return an instance is to just call `cls()`, which will call `__init__`.

---

But this is easy to get around: just have the alternate constructors pass some extra argument to `__init__` meaning "skip the usual initialization, I'm going to do it later". For example:

```
def __init__(self, name="", revision=None, _skip_default_init=False):
    # blah blah

@classmethod
def from_file(cls, filename=""):
    # blah blah setup
    obj = cls(_skip_default_init=True)
    # extra initialization work
    return obj
```

If you want to make this less visible, you can always take `**kwargs` and check it inside the method body… but remember, this is Python; you can't prevent people from doing stupid things, all you can do is make it obvious that they're stupid. And the `_skip_default_init` should be more than enough to handle that.

---

If you really want to, you can override `__new__` as well. Constructing an object doesn't call `__init__` unless `__new__` returns an instance of `cls` or some subclass thereof. So, you can give `__new__` a flag that tells it to skip over `__init__` by munging `obj.__class__`, then restore the `__class__` yourself. This is really hacky, but could conceivably be useful.

---

A much cleaner solution—but for some reason even less common in Python—is to borrow the "class cluster" idea from Smalltalk/ObjC: Create a private subclass that has a different `__init__` that doesn't `super` (or intentionally skips over its immediate base and `super`s from there), and then have your alternate constructor in the base class just return an instance of that subclass.

---

Alternatively, if the only reason you don't want to call `__init__` is so you can do the exact same thing `__init__` would have done… why? DRY stands for "don't repeat yourself", not "bend over backward to find ways to force yourself to repeat yourself", right?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very clear and useful answer! Exactly what I was hoping for.