# Calling instance method from class method, allowed in python3, disallowed in python 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, class-method

The following code snippet gives error in python2 but no error with python3

```
class Steps(object):
    def step(self, msg="Default"):
        if not hasattr(self, "funky_attr"):
            print('No attr')
        print(self)
        print(msg)

class FirstTest(Steps):
    @classmethod
    def test_setup(cls):
      cls.step("This is the message")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    C = FirstTest()
    C.test_setup()
```

With python 2 it produces the error:

> TypeError: unbound method step() must be called with CifsTest instance
> as first argument (got str instance instead)

While with python 3 it runs fine:

> No attr
>
> This is the message    # Note here the 'self' is the str
>
> Default

Is this the correct behavior ?

Python3 allows calling instance method from class methods ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3 methods are regular function objects (not "unbound method" instances) and therefore they do not check that the first argument is an instance of the class.

Not sure why this change was considered important (uniformity or performance, probably) but what you observed looks like an unwanted side effect of this choice.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. A couple of days ago I need to do this(call instance method from classmethod) when I came across this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427379/python-how-to-call-an-instance-method-from-a-class-method-of-the-same-class And it seems, that is not entirely correct

Comment: @mittal in that question the answer suggests a change so an instance method will call a class method. (the *since it is a instance method* part in the explanation applies to `__init__()`)

Comment: @tevemadar Yes I could do that but I don't own the code of master class :) But now I know that with python 3 I can just pass anything (even None) and call instance method from `classmethod`