# call a method inside classmethod in python

Tags: python

I am learning python and stucked in a problem

Suppose I have a class:

```
class Xyz:
    def __init__(self):
        self.number=25
    
    def square(self):
        return self.number*self.number
    
    @classmethod
    def getsquare(cls):
        return cls.square()

#Now let's call getsquare() method
sq=Xyz.getsquare()
```

I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: square() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

My attempt:

I tried to make square() function as `classmethod` and then calling the getsquare() method but still I am getting an error
(I guess it was because since we aren't creating an object of class so due to this number is not initialising)

but if I do like this it's working:

```
class Xyz:
    
    def square():
        number=25
        return number*number
    
    @classmethod
    def getsquare(cls):
        return cls.square()
```

**so How to call a class function inside classmethod?**

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427379/python-how-to-call-an-instance-method-from-a-class-method-of-the-same-class

Comment: @MSH sir it's somehow related but It doesn't solved my issue!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "class function". The only thing I can think that it might mean is... the same thing that `classmethod` means. But `square` *is not* a `classmethod` - it's an ordinary instance method. To call it, you need an *instance*. To be able to do `return self.number*self.number`, there has to be a `self` to get the `number` from. But the *point* of `@classmethod` is that you call `getsquare` *without* such an object. What you are trying to do doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Please read/watch https://speakerdeck.com/pyconslides/pythons-class-development-toolkit-by-raymond-hettinger to make sure you understand what `classmethod` is for and how to use it.

Comment: I agree with the above comments. If `number` is always 25 why make a class in the first place?

Comment: @Ch3steR sir that was just for practice purpose

Comment: @KarlKnechtel sir that's what I want...I just want to call square() function inside getsquare() function(which is basically a class method) and I tried to make an object like you said in the comment by `Xyz().square()` and `cls().square()` but it is not working..pls guide me

Comment: The guidance you need right now is to read a tutorial. It is not possible to simply answer the question and have you actually understand what is going on. You have to understand the *underlying concepts* first. Stack Overflow is *not a discussion forum* and therefore not the place to get that kind of help with programming.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thank you sir for advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cls` is just an uninstantiated class object, calling `return cls.square()` is analogous to calling `Xyz.square()`, which obviously doesn't work because its not a `@classmethod`. Try first initiating the class inside `getsquare` before calling any methods:

```
class Xyz:
    def __init__(self):
        self.number=25
    
    def square(self):
        return self.number*self.number
    
    @classmethod
    def getsquare(cls):
        return cls().square()

#Now let's call getsquare() method
sq=Xyz.getsquare()
```

<strike>Why the second example works, the simple answer is because it doesn't have an `__init__` defined so it's doesn't know how to initialize so it's not needed.</strike> Check comment

Comment: The second part of this answer is nonsense. There is always an `__init__` method because one is inherited from the base `object` type. The reason the second example works is because `square` was defined without a `self` parameter. However, this makes `square` *not* a valid instance method. It can *only* be called like `Xyz.square()`, and not like `Xyz().square()`. (A properly decorated `@staticmethod` could be called either of those ways.)

Answer (score 1):

Some mistakes I see here, but I am going to answer the syntax question

`@classmethod`/`@staticmethod` decorate a method as a static member for the class. By definition, they do not reference to any object and have several restrictions:

- They can only directly call other static method
- They can only directly access static data
- They cannot refer to self or super in any way

In your code, `getsquare` is a static method and `square` is a instance method. So, `getsquare` violates the first rule because of it is calling to `square`